# Javascript new difference tab after click

Tags: javascript

I can open a new tab on click with `window.open()` but after five clicks, I have only one new tab.

What I need is 5 new tabs after 5 click in js.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can give each window a name and then it will open up in a new tab:

[More information about `window.open`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

```html
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.co.uk', 'window1')">window1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.co.uk', 'window2')">window2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.co.uk', 'window3')">window3</a>
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.co.uk', 'window4')">window4</a>
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.co.uk', 'window5')">window5</a>
```

[Example fiddle as snippet blocks `window.open` js](http://jsfiddle.net/4o6v2drb/)

Comment: But i need do it on same button. Sorry i dont explan it closely.